# Jmeter Recording Controller is not working when use for url localhost

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter.
I used recording controller to record the script .When I record url like www.google.com then its recording but when I record url localhost/test/users/login then its not getting record.I am using xampp apache local server at port 80,443

I did setting in browser
[image]

I have refer this link
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove from firefox configuration in No Proxy For:

> localhost, 127.0.0.1

And ensure you start Recorder

Comment: Not worked, I removed ,localhost, 127.0.0.1 but displayed error  message "The proxy server is refusing connections"

Comment: you didn't Start rhe recorder

Comment: Its worked but if I include URL pattern .*\.html then its not working.Why so